# Need to retrieve most recent mobile phone from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

I'm trying to format data coming from a JSON webhook in Zapier. What I need to return is the latest mobile number. I'm using this code to get this result.

```
const text = inputData.text.split("|||")
let obj = {}
output = [{text}];
```

**This is the output I get:**

```
text
1
8/1/2022***(4X5) 459-103X***landline
2
1/10/2020***(4X5) 710-303X***mobile
3
6/15/2017***(4X5) 456-145s***landline
4
6/15/2017***(4X5) 454-135X***landline
5
6/15/2017***(4X5) 459-088X***landline
id
t1KZMxj29X8R8TObOkT65MMD6LZAuUdc
runtime_meta
memory_used_mb
63
duration_ms
52
logs
async
false
```

Comment: If it's a "JSON hook" why isn't your response JSON?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what input created that output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the text to work with:

```
8/1/2022***(4X5) 459-103X***landline
1/10/2020***(4X5) 710-303X***mobile
6/15/2017***(4X5) 456-145s***landline
6/15/2017***(4X5) 454-135X***landline
6/15/2017***(4X5) 459-088X***landline
```

If it's not, then just ignore all lines without the `***` separator.

```js
var str = `
8/1/2022***(4X5) 459-103X***landline
1/10/2020***(4X5) 710-303X***mobile
6/15/2017***(4X5) 456-145s***landline
6/15/2017***(4X5) 454-135X***landline
6/15/2017***(4X5) 459-088X***landline
11/11/2021***(4X5) 710-222X***mobile
09/21/2020***(4X5) 710-111X***mobile

`;
var lines = str.split("\n");
var arr = [];
lines.forEach(function(line) {
  var arr_line = line.split("***");
  if (arr_line.length == 3) {
    arr.push({
      date: getTime(arr_line[0]),
      phone: arr_line[1],
      type: arr_line[2]
    })
  }
})
var max_date = null;
var phone = null;
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (obj.date > max_date || !max_date) {
    if (obj.type == 'mobile') {
      max_date = obj.date;
      phone = obj.phone
    }
  }
})

function getTime(str) {
  var arr = str.split("/");
  return new Date(+arr[2], +arr[0]-1, +arr[1]).getTime();
}

console.log(phone)
```